# Search for a folder with a certain name on mac?

Tags: mac

How can I search for a folder of a certain name on mac? I need to limit the search to be within a different folder. I can easily do this for file names but I cant see how to do the same for folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, all you need to do is change the search kind to ***Folder***

[image]

In this case I am searching inside the Folder `Constantine` for anything with Kind set as Folder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything. The default search, before you click the 'filename' drop-menu is already 'files, folders & contents'

[image]

Clicking 'Name Matches' will reduce that to 'files & folders'

[image]

You can add a search parameter for 'Kind' is 'Folder' but only if you have too many matches to quickly scroll through. [Click where the red square is, which will turn from + to - once you do.]

[image]